# ImageView not populated with Image Uri using Picasso

Tags: java, android, uri, picasso

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220529/dynamically-setting-imageview-setimageuri-not-displaying-image) is my previous attempt at dynamically setting an `ImageView`.  It was suggested that I use an image library, so I decided to use Picasso:

Here is my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Here is the Image URI:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A48
```

Resource code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imageDisplayer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And how I load the images into the ImageView:

```
public void LoadImages(ArrayList<PhotoPath> photos){
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageDisplayer);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (photos != null) {
            for (PhotoPath photo : photos) {
                Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(photo.getPhotoPath());

                params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                //imageView.setImageURI(photoUri);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                Picasso.get().load(photoUri)
                        .resize(100, 100)
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_account)
                        .into(imageView);

                layout.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the `error` mipmap is showing, even though the `photoUri` is not null.

Is there something wrong with my `Uri`?

Comment: remove the `.error(R.mipmap.ic_account)` part

Comment: Have you tried `Picasso.with (this).load....`   ???

Comment: 1. Call `layout.addView(imageView);`  before loading. 
2.Check for valid `URI`.
3. Put a response listener to check the exception.

Comment: @ADM Could you be a bit more precise? Maybe an example?

Comment: @ZobairIbnAlam Why must I remove the .error part??