# Set an ImageView from a Uri

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, uri

```
private File createImageFile() {
        File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String timeStamp = sdf.format(new Date());

        File imageFile = new File(picturesDirectory, "picture" + timeStamp +".jpg");

        SharedPreferences fileLocation = getSharedPreferences("filePath", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = fileLocation.edit();
        editor.putString("file", imageFile.toString());
        ImageView photoImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoImg);
        photoImg.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        editor.commit();

        return imageFile;
    }
```

I'm trying to display an image taken using the camera intent, however, after the picture is taken the image doesn't get displayed in my ImageView. The image definitely does get saved as I can view it in my gallery.

I've looked around on stackoverflow and none of the answers seem to be working for me, i've tried using BitmapFactory but that also doesn't work. Any input will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this `imageFile` even exists ? `new File()` does not create a File.

Comment: If  `URI` is valid . Follow [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220731/4168607).

Comment: Is there an exception thrown when you run this code? It would help to know what we're dealing with, if that's the case. Check the logcat when this happens and see if you can find any errors or warnings, and let us know if you find anything relevant.

Comment: @ADM the image file does exist at the path as it is avaliable in my gallery, im also able to share the image through the app, just can't seem to get it to display in an imageview

Answer (score 0):

Use the code this will help you

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");   
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void takePhotoFromCamera() {

        str_SaveFolderName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder_name";
        str_randomnumber = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        wallpaperDirectory = new File(str_SaveFolderName);
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        str_Camera_Photo_ImageName = str_randomnumber + ".jpg";
        str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath = str_SaveFolderName + "/" + str_randomnumber + ".jpg";

        System.err.println(" str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath  " + str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);

        f = new File(str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).
                putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)), Take_Photo);

    }
```

And onActivityResult() -

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == Take_Photo) {

            imageview.setImageBitmap(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
                            R.id.simpleImageView, 100, 100));
        }
}
```