# Image not loading through Glide after picking from gallery

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I create an intent to let the user pick an image from their gallery:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);
```

Then, after the user picks an image, I handle it here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE) {
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();

        Glide.with(context)
            .load(new File(uri.getPath()))
            .into(myImageView);
    }
}
```

The URI looks something like this:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F43/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fpng/2098318161
```

But it's not loading the image into the ImageView, and I don't know why.

Comment: You already got a perfect alternativ. But new File(uri.getPath()) did not work as the File class expects a file system path which is not delivered by getPath(). Just have a look at its value and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

you can load it in to the imageView like this;
`myImageView.setImageURI(uri);`

Comment: Not really an option for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220731/13770904

Comment: Why would not that be an option? You can put most code in a thread if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, If you pass an Uri instance, In normal case it will start like this (file://) but in yours it doesn't have a correct schema .
You can check how Uri, String and File models are loaded.

Second thing, If your using a testing device whose api level is >= 29 then you have to add a flag in manifest to access the storage.

```
requestLegacyExternalStorage=true
```

Also check your result code if it's returning 0 or -1